# Having trouble scraping shopify product pages for product details using google importxml

Tags: google-sheets, scrape

I'm trying to use importxml in google sheets to scrape the product details for all products. but am having trouble extracting the links to the product pages.

trying to use the below query

`=importxml("http://au.boohoo.com/womens/dresses/new-in","//div[@class='thumb-link']/@href")`

All I keep getting is "imported content is empty"

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is `thumb-link` in `<a>` element. So how about this?

```
=importxml("http://au.boohoo.com/womens/dresses/new-in", "//a[@class='thumb-link']/@href")
```

Comment: thanks for that - works great. Do you know if this function also works on https:// sites ?

Comment: @DataDancer  At [the help document of ``IMPORTXML``](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en), there is a sample that ``https://`` is used. But I don't know whether the data can be retrieved from the URL you want. It is required to try.